# installing Linux/Apache - unable to connect

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

It's my first time installing Linux/Apache. I loaded CentOS and LAMPP on a machine attached to a LAN.

Turned off http and mysql (because I didn't want conflict with LLAMPP)

```
chkconfig httpd off
chkconfig mysqld off
```

then successfully LAMPP started with

```
/opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.7.3a...
XAMPP: Starting Apache with SSL (and PHP5)...
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...
XAMPP for Linux started.
```

**Problem: Unable to connect - Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 179.16.51.36.**

**I need some pointers as to where to look next.**

No errors in error_log file (just some warnings)

I can ping server.

httpd.conf looks like this:

```
ServerRoot "/opt/lampp"
Listen 80

ServerAdmin you@example.com

ServerName 179.16.51.36

DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog logs/error_log
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog logs/access_log common
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/opt/lampp/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
</IfModule>

<Directory "/opt/lampp/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>


EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile off
```

Once I start LAMPP, I am able to telnet into localhost, port 80

```
telnet localhost 80
[root@lastest /]# telnet localhost 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1).
Escape character is '^]'.
```

file /var/log/messages contains the following. I am not sure what is useful here.

```
# cat /var/log/messages
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ACPI: Processor [CPU0] (supports 8 throttling states)
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: Real Time Clock Driver v1.12ac
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: Non-volatile memory driver v1.2
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: Linux agpgart interface v0.101 (c) Dave Jones
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: agpgart: Detected an Intel 845G Chipset.
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: agpgart: Detected 892K stolen memory.
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: agpgart: AGP aperture is 128M @ 0xf0000000
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: Serial: 8250/16550 driver $Revision: 1.90 $ 4 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: 00:08: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: brd: module loaded
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: Uniform Multi-Platform E-IDE driver Revision: 7.00alpha2
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ide: Assuming 33MHz system bus speed for PIO modes; override with idebus=xx
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ICH4: IDE controller at PCI slot 0000:00:1f.1
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: PCI: Enabling device 0000:00:1f.1 (0005 -> 0007)
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ACPI: PCI Interrupt 0000:00:1f.1[A] -> GSI 18 (level, low) -> IRQ 169
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ICH4: chipset revision 1
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ICH4: not 100% native mode: will probe irqs later
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel:     ide0: BM-DMA at 0xffa0-0xffa7, BIOS settings: hda:DMA, hdb:pio
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: hda: ST340014A, ATA DISK drive
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ide0 at 0x1f0-0x1f7,0x3f6 on irq 14
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: hda: max request size: 512KiB
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: hda: 78156288 sectors (40016 MB) w/2048KiB Cache, CHS=16383/255/63, UDMA(100)
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: hda: cache flushes supported
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel:  hda: hda1 hda2
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ide-floppy driver 0.99.newide
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: usbcore: registered new driver hiddev
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: usbcore: registered new driver usbhid
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: drivers/usb/input/hid-core.c: v2.6:USB HID core driver
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: PNP: No PS/2 controller found. Probing ports directly.
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: mice: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: md: md driver 0.90.3 MAX_MD_DEVS=256, MD_SB_DISKS=27
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: md: bitmap version 4.39
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: TCP bic registered
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: Initializing IPsec netlink socket
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: NET: Registered protocol family 1
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: NET: Registered protocol family 17
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: Using IPI No-Shortcut mode
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ACPI: (supports S0 S1 S3 S4 S5)
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: Initalizing network drop monitor service
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: Freeing unused kernel memory: 228k freed
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 410k
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: Time: tsc clocksource has been installed.
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ACPI: PCI Interrupt 0000:00:1d.7[D] -> GSI 23 (level, low) -> IRQ 177
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: EHCI Host Controller
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: debug port 1
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: irq 177, io mem 0xffa7fc00
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00, driver 10 Dec 2004
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: usb usb1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: hub 1-0:1.0: 6 ports detected
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver v3.0
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ACPI: PCI Interrupt 0000:00:1d.0[A] -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 185
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: UHCI Host Controller
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: irq 185, io base 0x0000e800
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: usb usb2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: hub 2-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ACPI: PCI Interrupt 0000:00:1d.1[B] -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 193
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: UHCI Host Controller
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: irq 193, io base 0x0000e880
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: usb usb3: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: hub 3-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ACPI: PCI Interrupt 0000:00:1d.2[C] -> GSI 18 (level, low) -> IRQ 169
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: UHCI Host Controller
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: irq 169, io base 0x0000ec00
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: usb usb4: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: hub 4-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: usb 2-2: new low speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 2
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: SCSI subsystem initialized
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: usb 2-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: input: Darfon USB Combo Keyboard as /class/input/input0
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: input: USB HID v1.00 Keyboard [Darfon USB Combo Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-2
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: device-mapper: ioctl: 4.11.5-ioctl (2007-12-12) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: input: Darfon USB Combo Keyboard as /class/input/input1
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: input: USB HID v1.00 Device [Darfon USB Combo Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-2
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: device-mapper: dm-raid45: initialized v0.2594l
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: EXT3-fs: mounted filesystem with ordered data mode.
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: type=1404 audit(1295359707.879:2): enforcing=1 old_enforcing=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: type=1403 audit(1295359708.177:3): policy loaded auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ACPI: PCI Interrupt 0000:00:1f.3[B] -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 201
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: parport: PnPBIOS parport detected.
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: parport0: PC-style at 0x378, irq 7 [PCSPP,TRISTATE,EPP]
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: i810_smbus 0000:00:02.0: i810/i815 i2c device found.
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ACPI: PCI Interrupt 0000:01:03.0[A] -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 193
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: 3c59x: Donald Becker and others.  www.scyld.com/network/vortex.html
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: 0000:01:03.0: 3Com PCI 3c905B Cyclone 100baseTx at f89c2c00.
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: e100: Intel(R) PRO/100 Network Driver, 3.5.10-k3-NAPI
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: e100: Copyright(c) 1999-2005 Intel Corporation
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ACPI: PCI Interrupt 0000:01:08.0[A] -> GSI 20 (level, low) -> IRQ 209
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: e100: eth1: e100_probe: addr 0xff8fe000, irq 209, MAC addr 00:03:47:2C:9F:15
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ACPI: PCI Interrupt 0000:00:1f.5[B] -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 201
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: intel_rng: Firmware space is locked read-only. If you can't or
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: intel_rng: don't want to disable this in firmware setup, and if
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: intel_rng: you are certain that your system has a functional
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: intel_rng: RNG, try using the 'no_fwh_detect' option.
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: input: PC Speaker as /class/input/input2
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: intel8x0_measure_ac97_clock: measured 51010 usecs
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: intel8x0: clocking to 48000
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: Floppy drive(s): fd0 is 1.44M
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: FDC 0 is a post-1991 82077
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: lp0: using parport0 (interrupt-driven).
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: lp0: console ready
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: NET: Registered protocol family 10
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: IPv6 over IPv4 tunneling driver
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ACPI: Power Button (FF) [PWRF]
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ACPI: Sleep Button (CM) [SLPB]
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ACPI: Mapper loaded
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: dell-wmi: No known WMI GUID found
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: md: Autodetecting RAID arrays.
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: md: autorun ...
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: md: ...  autorun DONE.
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: device-mapper: multipath: version 1.0.5 loaded
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: loop: loaded (max 8 devices)
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: EXT3 FS on dm-0, internal journal
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: EXT3 FS on hda1, internal journal
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: EXT3-fs: mounted filesystem with ordered data mode.
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: Adding 4128760k swap on /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:4128760k
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: IA-32 Microcode Update Driver: v1.14a <tigran@veritas.com>
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: microcode: CPU0 updated from revision 0xb to 0x1e, date = 06052003
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: Netfilter messages via NETLINK v0.30.
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ip_conntrack version 2.4 (8192 buckets, 65536 max) - 228 bytes per conntrack
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: e100: eth0: e100_watchdog: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex
Jan 18 09:09:02 mtlastest kernel: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Jan 18 09:09:03 mtlastest rpc.statd[2088]: Version 1.0.9 Starting
Jan 18 09:09:04 mtlastest hcid[2148]: Bluetooth HCI daemon
Jan 18 09:09:04 mtlastest kernel: Bluetooth: Core ver 2.10
Jan 18 09:09:04 mtlastest kernel: NET: Registered protocol family 31
Jan 18 09:09:04 mtlastest kernel: Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Jan 18 09:09:04 mtlastest kernel: Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Jan 18 09:09:04 mtlastest hcid[2148]: Register path:/org/bluez fallback:1
Jan 18 09:09:04 mtlastest kernel: Bluetooth: L2CAP ver 2.8
Jan 18 09:09:04 mtlastest kernel: Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Jan 18 09:09:04 mtlastest sdpd[2154]: Bluetooth SDP daemon
Jan 18 09:09:04 mtlastest kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Jan 18 09:09:04 mtlastest kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Jan 18 09:09:04 mtlastest kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.8
Jan 18 09:09:05 mtlastest pcscd: pcscdaemon.c:507:main() pcsc-lite 1.4.4 daemon ready.
Jan 18 09:09:05 mtlastest pcscd: hotplug_libusb.c:402:HPEstablishUSBNotifications() Driver ifd-egate.bundle does not support IFD_GENERATE_HOTPLUG. Using active polling instead.
Jan 18 09:09:05 mtlastest pcscd: hotplug_libusb.c:411:HPEstablishUSBNotifications() Polling forced every 1 second(s)
Jan 18 09:09:11 mtlastest kernel: Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.1
Jan 18 09:09:11 mtlastest hidd[2275]: Bluetooth HID daemon
Jan 18 09:09:12 mtlastest automount[2295]: lookup_read_master: lookup(nisplus): couldn't locate nis+ table auto.master
Jan 18 09:09:14 mtlastest gpm[2367]: *** info [startup.c(95)]:
Jan 18 09:09:14 mtlastest gpm[2367]: Started gpm successfully. Entered daemon mode.
Jan 18 09:09:16 mtlastest avahi-daemon[2449]: Found user 'avahi' (UID 70) and group 'avahi' (GID 70).
Jan 18 09:09:16 mtlastest avahi-daemon[2449]: Successfully dropped root privileges.
Jan 18 09:09:16 mtlastest avahi-daemon[2449]: avahi-daemon 0.6.16 starting up.
Jan 18 09:09:16 mtlastest avahi-daemon[2449]: WARNING: No NSS support for mDNS detected, consider installing nss-mdns!
Jan 18 09:09:16 mtlastest avahi-daemon[2449]: Successfully called chroot().
Jan 18 09:09:16 mtlastest avahi-daemon[2449]: Successfully dropped remaining capabilities.
Jan 18 09:09:16 mtlastest avahi-daemon[2449]: No service found in /etc/avahi/services.
Jan 18 09:09:16 mtlastest avahi-daemon[2449]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jan 18 09:09:16 mtlastest avahi-daemon[2449]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::203:47ff:fe2c:9f15.
Jan 18 09:09:16 mtlastest avahi-daemon[2449]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jan 18 09:09:16 mtlastest avahi-daemon[2449]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 169.16.51.36.
Jan 18 09:09:16 mtlastest avahi-daemon[2449]: Network interface enumeration completed.
Jan 18 09:09:16 mtlastest avahi-daemon[2449]: Registering new address record for fe80::203:47ff:fe2c:9f15 on eth0.
Jan 18 09:09:16 mtlastest avahi-daemon[2449]: Registering new address record for 169.16.51.36 on eth0.
Jan 18 09:09:16 mtlastest avahi-daemon[2449]: Registering HINFO record with values 'I686'/'LINUX'.
Jan 18 09:09:17 mtlastest avahi-daemon[2449]: Server startup complete. Host name is mtlastest.local. Local service cookie is 98803198.
Jan 18 09:09:18 mtlastest smartd[2509]: smartd version 5.38 [i686-redhat-linux-gnu] Copyright (C) 2002-8 Bruce Allen
Jan 18 09:09:18 mtlastest smartd[2509]: Home page is http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/
Jan 18 09:09:18 mtlastest smartd[2509]: Opened configuration file /etc/smartd.conf
Jan 18 09:09:18 mtlastest smartd[2509]: Configuration file /etc/smartd.conf was parsed, found DEVICESCAN, scanning devices
Jan 18 09:09:18 mtlastest smartd[2509]: Problem creating device name scan list
Jan 18 09:09:18 mtlastest smartd[2509]: Device: /dev/hda, opened
Jan 18 09:09:18 mtlastest smartd[2509]: Device: /dev/hda, found in smartd database.
Jan 18 09:09:18 mtlastest smartd[2509]: Device: /dev/hda, is SMART capable. Adding to "monitor" list.
Jan 18 09:09:18 mtlastest smartd[2509]: Monitoring 1 ATA and 0 SCSI devices
Jan 18 09:09:18 mtlastest smartd[2511]: smartd has fork()ed into background mode. New PID=2511.
Jan 18 09:09:19 mtlastest init: open(/dev/pts/0): No such file or directory
Jan 18 09:09:21 mtlastest kernel: [drm] Initialized drm 1.0.1 20051102
Jan 18 09:09:21 mtlastest kernel: ACPI: PCI Interrupt 0000:00:02.0[A] -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 185
Jan 18 09:09:21 mtlastest kernel: [drm] Initialized i915 1.8.0 20060929 on minor 0
Jan 18 09:09:23 mtlastest pcscd: winscard.c:304:SCardConnect() Reader E-Gate 0 0 Not Found
[root@mtlastest ~]# Jan 18 09:37:23 mtlastest proftpd[2995]: mtlastest - ProFTPD 1.3.2c (maint) (built Fri Dec 11 08:46:41 CET 2009) standalone mode STARTUP .



netstat .ntlp something looks fishy
here..


Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign AddState  PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:998   0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN 2088/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN 2961/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111   0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN 2056/portmap
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631 0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN 2326/cupsd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN 2348/sendmail: ace
tcp        0      0 :::80         :::*       LISTEN 2813/httpd
tcp        0      0 :::21         :::*       LISTEN 2995/proftpd: (ace
tcp        0      0 :::22         :::*       LISTEN 2315/sshd
tcp        0      0 :::443        :::*       LISTEN 2813/httpd
```

Answer (score 1):

From the machine, run `telnet localhost 80`.  Does that work?  If so it indicates your webserver is running on port 80 like it should be.  From your description though it sounds like that isn't working.

Check `/var/log/messages` to see if anything useful is being printed there.

This [XAMPP page](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html#377) has some further troubleshooting tips. I suspect you will find some syslog messages in /var/log/messages that should point you in the right direction, though.

Comment: I have not `/var/log/messages`. What should I do ?

Comment: @abuabu try this: `sudo journactl -xe`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your iptables is allowing incoming connections on port 80.

Run `iptables -L -nv` and make sure you have a line like this:

```
 2383  138K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80
```

in your INPUT table.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are trying to connect by 179.16.51.36 ip in browser and you are checking the server via localhost. Can you tell if loading localhost in browser works. If the client and server are different hosts. Then you should be checking if the telnet from client to server ip on port 80 is working ?

Answer (score 0):

You should verify Apache started correctly before you attempt to access it over the network.

`netstat -ntlp`

Run the above on the server and it should list which services are running and which ports they are "bound" to.

If 80 is not listed then you need to troubleshoot the apache startup.

```
apachectl configtest
apachectl start
```

Temporarily turning off the servers iptables firewall during initial testing will help.

```
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
```

Comment: 3764/httpd seems to be on port 0 (see ablve)

Comment: +1 to turning iptables off!

Comment: apachectl configtest gives me:
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName

Comment: It's rather unprofessional to be recommending iptables be turned off even when behind a firewall.